# Why Householder transformation can not be chosen to be an identity matrix?

Tags: householder, linear-algebra

For Householder transformation, we know that 
$H = I-uu^T$, where $\|u\|_2=\sqrt{2}$. When it acts on any vector $x$, $Hx$ and $x$ is symmetric with respect to $span(u)^T$. But I have read a monography "Stewart. Matrix Algorithm I: Basic Decomposition, 1998, SIAM". It is written as follows on Page 257:

> Combining these two observations we get Algorithm 1.1 — a program to generate
>   a Householder transformation. Note that when $x = 0$, any $u$ will do. In this case
>   the program housegen returns $u = 2e_1$, where $e_1$ is the first column of an identity matrix. This choice does not make $H$ the identity,
>   but the identity with its $(1,1)$-element changed to $-1$. (In fact, it is easy to see that
>   a Householder transformation can never be the identity matrix, since it transforms $u$into $-u$.)

My question is that I donot understand why the Householder matrixcannot be an identity matrix. Because when $x=0$, it means that we donot need to do any transformation, i.e., we can take $H = I$ identity matrix. But the author said we cannot take identity matrix. Where do I misunderstand? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, the Householder transformation is a reflection about a plane or hyperplane. The plane is described by its **unit normal vector** u and the transformation is then H = I - 2uu'. If u is a unit vector, 2uu' cannot be zero and thus H cannot be the identity matrix.

You can find plenty of non-Householder transformations H that, for certain arguments, give the same result as some Householder transform. H = I for x = 0 is one such example. Yet f(x) = x is not the same as f(x) = x² even though f(0) = 0 is true for both of them.

Comment: Thanks very much for you reply. I got it.  ;). by the way, could you please write the equations in math mode for more accurate expressions, eg., `$H=I-2*u*u'$` mode. Thanks. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Short answer:

When he says that when $x=0$, any $u$ will do, he means any $u$ that satisfies $\|u\|_2 = \sqrt{2}$. Otherwise, it wouldn't be a Householder reflector.

So yes, you have found a transformation that "introduces" zeros in $x$, but you haven't proven that that transformation is a Householder reflector (spoiler: it isn't ;) ).